# org.dozer.MappingException: error

Tags: java, hibernate, dozer, mappingexception

i have two pojo class which contain same field private String nameId;

my dozermapping.xml file contain

```
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net                               http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
      <mapping map-id="a"> 
    <class-a>com.ihx.util.Fileobject</class-a>
    <class-b>com.ihx.model.Test</class-b>   
    <field>
    <a>nameId</a>
    <b>nameId</b>
    </field> 
  </mapping>  
  </mappings>
```

i m getting an error which is given below

```
org.dozer.MappingException Property 'nameId' not found in Class: class java.lang.String`
```

my code contain contain

```
 List myMappingFiles = new ArrayList();
                 myMappingFiles.add("dozerMapping.xml");
                // myMappingFiles.add("someOtherDozerBeanMappings.xml");
                 DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
                 mapper.setMappingFiles(myMappingFiles);
                 String p="com.ihx.util.Fileobject";
                 String p1="com.ihx.model.Test";
                 mapper.map(p, p1, "a");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List myMappingFiles = new ArrayList();
myMappingFiles.add("dozerMapping.xml");
// myMappingFiles.add("someOtherDozerBeanMappings.xml");
DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
mapper.setMappingFiles(myMappingFiles);
com.ihx.util.Fileobject p= new Fileobject();
p.setNameId("testNameId");
com.ihx.model.Test p1 = new com.ihx.model.Test();
mapper.map(p, p1, "a");
String mappedNameId = p1.getNameId();
// This mappedNameId should now be the testNameId we set earlier.
```

p and p1 need to be the actual class objects to transform, with the data in. p1 then gets the data mapped into it from p.

Comment: String p="com.ihx.util.Fileobject";
 String p1="com.ihx.model.Test";   this are the two pojo class...does i need to create object for the class separately

Comment: how to initiate  the dozermapping.xml from java class

Comment: I've updated the code snippet in my answer accordingly. (sorry for the delay, was on lunch!)